# Rendering not finished in Loaded event

Tags: wpf, animation, opacity, loaded

I subscribed to the wpf window's Loaded event: `Loaded += loaded;` and try to change the opacity of some controls in code behind.
I notice that in the method `loaded` the controls are not painted by wpf yet. So the code has no effect, the rendering of the controls occurs only after the method is exited.

1) Is there another event e.g. `Rendered` that I can subscribe to?

EDIT: I just discovered that there is an OnContentRendered event and the following code works:
Although an animation is probably preferrable.

```
protected override void OnContentRendered(EventArgs e)
{
   base.OnContentRendered(e);
   for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
   {
       Parentpanel.Opacity += 0.01;
       Splashscreen.Opacity -= 0.01;
       Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { }), DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle, null);
       Thread.Sleep(50);
   }
}
```

Otherwise I probably have to use an animation that changes the opacity of usercontrol1 from 0.1 to 1.0 and of usercontrol2 from 1.0 to 0.0.

2) Do you know an example for such an animation?

Comment: Where are your controls defined? For example, if they are defined in a `ControlTemplate`, then they will probably not be ready by the time the `Loaded` event is raised. In this instance, you would need to handle the [`FrameworkElement.OnApplyTemplate` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.onapplytemplate.aspx).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your Loaded handler you can post the UI altering operation ( e.g. `void ChangeOpacity()` ) on the dispatcher:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Loaded, new Action(ChangeOpacity));
```

It will execute after the rendering is done.

Edit

I see you simply need an animation to start when the window opens. It's easily done in XAML, here's a working example generated in Blend:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="100" Width="200">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="myStoryboard">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)"
                         Storyboard.TargetName="myControl">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="0"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource myStoryboard}"/>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Window.Triggers>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox x:Name="myControl" Text="I'm disappearing..." />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Correct, your dispatcher looks better then my idea OnContentRendered, although after every step the dispatcher must be invoked for a refresh. The animation works and looks better.

Comment: This worked great for me, thank you. The Visual Basic .NET 4.5.1 equivalent for me was:

`Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(New Action(AddressOf methodName), Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Loaded)`

Answer (score 1):

I just recently was having issues while trying to render some standardized animation to WPF usercontrols when the visibility changed.  In my app, I have a couple singleton static classes. In one, I added a static method "VisibleFader" and you pass in the framework element control and it automatically attaches the event handler to the double-animation against the opacity property.  It works great and does not require ANY changes to any other Styles, Control Templates, or any other theme implementations.

```
public static DoubleAnimation da;
public static void VisibleFader(FrameworkElement fe)
{
   if (da == null)
   {
      da = new DoubleAnimation();
      da.From = 0;
      da.To = 1;
      da.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.7));
   }

   fe.IsVisibleChanged += myFader;
}

private static void myFader(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
   ((FrameworkElement)sender).BeginAnimation(FrameworkElement.OpacityProperty, da);
}
```

Then, in my class (such as your Loaded Event), I just call this static method with that "userControl" object.

```
MySingletonClass.VisibleFader( this.whateverUserControl );
```

Done...  So, when the visibility changes, it fades IN from nothing to 1.  And if something was having its visibilty to hidden, it's gone anyhow.

Comment: I will look in to this later, looks promising, see my edit btw.